# How to define custom variable for Delphi 7 search path in source code?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've a Delphi 7 project where I place common files used in other projects into Search Path.  Different versions of my project needs to use different versions of the common files.  I know it is possible to use Windows environment variables, but is it possible to define a variable search path within the .pas file?  Alternatively, I'm open to a work around method.

For example:

```
const Version = '100';
```

[image]

Comment: It won't do any good in the source code. It needs to be available to the IDE. You can add it to the .dpr file, with a full or relative path (Project->Add to project), or by manually editing the .dpr file (Project->View Source). Why can't you just put it in each project's options like normal?

Comment: Smells like you should be doing this with version control ....

Comment: If you incorporate the version number in the code file name you can refer to it in your pas file's uses clause and use a specific version in any project.

Answer (score 3):

> I know it is possible to use Windows environment variables

Or the IDE's own environment variables, so you do not have to mess with the Windows environment.  But yes, in general, what you are attempting to do can only be done using Environment Variables.

> is it possible to define a variable search path within the .pas file?

No, it is not.  Such a variable has to be defined at the OS/IDE layer, not at the code layer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just realize that the IDE environment variables is global so I can't assign a different value for the environment variable for different versions of my project.  I will need to reset the value of the environment variable every time I load a different version of my project.  Do you think there is a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This will I describe is a possible work around if you do not ask too much.

Suppose to have the folders that contain different versions distinguished by date or what you want. For example: `Project_14-07-21, Project_15-07-21, Project_16-07-21`.

Inside of these folders you can put your common folders with files with different versions. For example in any: `Project_16-07-21\Common`

At this point if you give up to information of sections [Version Info] and [Version Info Keys] in `dof` file, All that needs to be done is changing the file `cfg` e `dof` of the project.

How? In two words: **relative path**.

In file `dof` search `SearchPath` change in a similar way at this:

> SearchPath=..\DCU;DCU;..\Common;Common;$(DELPHI)\Lib;$(DELPHI)\JEDI\jvcl\lib\d7;$(DELPHI)\JEDI\jvcl\run;$(DELPHI)\JEDI\jcl\jcl\source\common

In file cfg change in a similar way at this:

> -U"..\DCU";"DCU";"..\Common";"Common";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Indy"
>   -I"..\DCU";"DCU";"..\Common";"Common";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Indy"
>   -R"..\DCU";"DCU";"..\Common";"Common";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Lib";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Indy"

with the necessary changes that they are useful at intention.

"Common" Refers to those internal folders "Common" of various versions projects.

instead "..\Common" you can think such as hard files that will not change in any version.

obviously also the file dpr will change according to paths

for example:
  ....
  JclSysUtils in '..\Common\JclSysUtils.pas',
  ....
  uTest in 'Common\uTest.pas';

{$R ..\Common\Project.tlb}
{$R ..\Common\Project.res}

At this point You can automate ALL BUT VERY ALL this via batch.

As a courtesy for example: I have realized batch file that compiling by dragging the `dpr` file.
these are their names by which we understand the purpose: `CC_IDE_Off.bat, CC_IDE_On.bat, CC_Debug_OnOff.bat`. With these batch that work by copying i file cfg e dof (of debug or not) in folders of the `dpr` file you can compiling complete projects even WITHOUT INSTALLING COMPONENTS into the IDE.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks to you the graceful changes. Good job. I really appreciated.

Comment: as result of tiredness I omitted some details: in the paths missing "Common" ecc.